# Converting 0 - 3.3 V to (-10) - 10 V with an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

My Teensy 3.6 microcontroller outputs an analog 0 V - 3.3 V signal.
I wish to use this to control a motor bidirectionally.
I wish to convert the 0 to 3.3 V swing signal to a -10 V to +10V swing signal.

When the motor controller receives a signal in the -10V to 0 V range the motor will run in reverse.

How do I convert 0 V to 3.3 V to -10 V to +10 V with an op-amp?
What kind of op-amp should I use?

Comment: It could be helpful to potential answerers if you said what kind of signal you were talking to. For instance, digital versus analogue.

Comment: 0 - 3.3 volt is the signal that my teensy 3.6 microcontroller gives off. I need op-amp to convert those signal to -10 - 10 to send it to a motor controller (so when I get a negative value, it makes the motor goes backward)

Comment: What voltage power supplies do you currently have or, are willing to add you your design?

Comment: To do this you want gain and offset. You want a non-inverting amplifier configuration with a gain of 20/3.3 and an offset of 3.3/2. Which op-amp? Depends on how fast your signal is. Something ancient like a 741 would probably do but maybe a TL071 or suchlike is a bit more modern.

Comment: As the Teensy provides a PWM signal for analog out, please add that to your question, and provide the carrier frequency. Also specify how much ripple is allowed on your +/- 10VDC output, and response time. This is a good question and deserves upvoting if you edit your question and add these specs.

Comment: If you are using the on-board DAC, you won't need much filtering, but you might still want to specify response time. There might be some glitches if the DAC output is not monotonic.

Comment: **SEPTEMBER 6TH** Closed and reopened to clear close vote queue. The question is a good one and was understandable and has several good answers, but some may not have understood it. My edit makes it still clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fze2Bm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Should have bypass capacitors on +/-12 to ground near the op-amp, of course.

Comment: AFAIK, the Teensy uses PWM for its analog output, so C1 and C2 may need to be much larger. The values will depend on the PWM frequency, amount of ripple allowed, and response time.

Comment: @PStechPaul   Teensy 3.6 has two 12-bit true DACs on the NXP Cortex M4 chip. See 3.6.3.2 on the chip datasheet for specifications.

Comment: I like this solution, but I think the parallel resistors won't do much. Mathematically they may make the  resistances more precise, but  even with a 1% tolerance,  the  error in the large resistances is comparable to the entirety of the small resistances. You can omit the larger ones in each pair without adding much  error, I believe.

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron The typical actual tolerance of E96 1% resistors is in the 0.3% range, so the parallel resistors will bring it much closer *typically*, and 1% resistors are virtually free. Or use E96 series 0.1% resistors for the lower (10k/6.65k/20k) values and 1% for the 665k and 887k at almost no additional cost. My concern here is mostly that the 50% value should be as close as possible to zero because that's where the motor is expected to be stopped.

Comment: A bigger variation is the 3.3V tolerance, but with the shown circuit it should cancel out at 50% DAC output. It won't cancel out at -10 and +10 output, of course, but that's a gain error. That's my thinking anyway. Of course it's probably 'good enough' with an LM358 instead of a  $3 op-amp and cheap 1% resistors and a couple trimpots too.

Comment: I used the parallel resistor trick in ranging analog controllers back in the day, and we were able to shave quite a bit off the calibration time by reducing the iterations.

Comment: It's probably not too critical to get exactly zero volts out for the motor to stop. The VFDs I've worked with have a zero speed frequency setting which is actually a low frequency output below which the motor will not turn. This is because an induction motor relies on a certain amount of slip to create torque, and there is a certain amount needed to overcome friction, inertia, and windage. This will typically be about 0.5-1.5 Hz, or up to 2% of full speed frequency. http://www.gohz.com/can-a-variable-frequency-drive-control-motor-at-zero-speed

Comment: These days when I post here, I just add trimmers to the circuits that will likely need them to get going if one doesn’t have a good resistor stash. Or promote software system calibration. With 1% resistors, this design can be calibrated to have 11 usable bits, or 1024 speed levels in each direction. That may well be acceptable (or not!).

Answer (score 3):

If an inverse relationship is acceptable (where 0V in gives 10V out and 3.3V in gives -10V out), then this will do the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsv4Cj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The opamp gain is set to 6 by R1 & R4, which should be close enough to your 6.06 requirement (20V / 3.3V), and the R2/R3 voltage divider produces about 1.414V, which results in a -10V offset when multiplied by the opamp's gain.

Note that you'll need to give the opamp appropriate supplies - in this case a dual +12V & -12V should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a linear relationship between input and output (for instance if the output is from a DAC, and is a proportional speed signal), then you require an amplifier configuration with the following relationship between output \$V_{OUT}\$ and input \$V_{IN}\$:

$$ V_{OUT} = 6.06(V_{IN}-1.65) $$

That's a non-inverting amplifier, with a gain of 6.06, and whose output is zero when the input is half way between zero and 3.3V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuqcbh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

If you are dealing with digital signals, the usual way to do this with an op-amp (if you insist on using an op-amp), is by having no feedback, and using it as a comparator. Better still, use an actual comparator. Here I use a normal op-amp, with rail-to-rail output, and supplies of ±10V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhSMTP.png)</sup>

R1 and R2 provide a reference voltage half way between the logic supply rails. The response will look like this:

[image]

Again, for digital signals, the following circuit may be more appropriate, using a couple of MOSFETS:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTKJu.png)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you find things a little too tight on the upper saturation limit of IC1a for comfort then increase the supply voltages to plus and minus 15 V.

[image: Voltage Scaler]